# I have a code which cycles images which are controlled by a button, I need it to show the images without having to press an image

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code which changes the image everytime the button is pressed. I have to change it so it cycles through the images without pressing a button. I don't know where to start with changing it to a free moving cycle. Help please

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var TL = new Array("Traffic Lights Red (4).jpg",
                         "Traffic Lights RY.jpg",
                         "Traffic Light Green.jpg",
                         "Traffic Lights Yellow.jpg",
                         "Traffic Lights Red (4).jpg")

      var Amount = 0;

      function lightCycle()
      {
        if(++Amount == 5)
          Amount = 0;

        document.images.banner.src = TL[Amount];
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="Traffic Lights Red (4).jpg" name="banner">

    <form>
      <input type="button" value="Change lights" name="Change lights" onclick="lightCycle()">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have a look at `window.setInterval(fn,ms)`, which takes a function `fn` and executes it every `ms` milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code, which will make it cycle on its own

```
    setInterval(lightCycle, 2000);
```

This will fire your lightCycle function, every 2000 milliseconds :)

Comment: I think this will only work, if ``lightCycle`` returns a function. You probably want this:  ``setInterval(lightCycle, 2000);`` withough the ``()``.

Comment: my bad!! thanks for the catch. fixed as per comment :)

Comment: Since you are not submitting any data to the server, you don't need the form tag.

Comment: I can't get it to work still, I took out the button command sequence and the form command replacing it with the command above. I tried with and without the body but when I run it only shows the setInterval code

Comment: can you update the code, it seems you are adding the setInterval code in HTML. it should be inside the script tag. If you are using jQuery, please add the setInterval code in `$(function() {})` so that is gets triggered after the DOM loads.

Comment: Thank you it works now, I didnt put it in the script.